# Lua function not returning the values

Tags: lua

I'm trying to write a `lua` function in which I pass two rectangles coordinates and receive the values on polar coordinates. Somehow the code I wrote returns an error and I can't see where I went wrong. How do I fix it?

```
io.write("Enter first coord: ")
F = io.read()
io.write("Enter second coord: ")
S = io.read()

A = tonumber(F)
T = tonumber(S)

getPolar(A,T)

function getPolar(x,y)
    mag = math.sqrt(x^2+y^2)
    ang = math.atan(y/x)
    return print("Magnitude: " .. tostring(mag) .. " Angle: " .. tostring(ang))
end
```

The error I receive is the following:

> Polar.lua:9: attempt to call a nil value (global 'getPolar') stack
>   traceback:
>           Polar.lua:9: in main chunk
>           [C]: in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is interpreted line by line.

You're calling `getPolar` befor you define it.

Move to function call behind the function definition to fix that.

Please note that `print` does not return a value so you can omit the `return` in your function.

You should use local variables wherever you can. It would make sense to restrict the scope of `mag` and `ang` to your function body.

Use `math.atan2` to calculate the angle as it will handle the quadrants correctly.
 See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctan2

```
function getPolar(x,y)
    local mag = math.sqrt(x^2+y^2)
    local ang = math.atan2(x,y)
    return mag, ang
end

local mag, ang = getPolar(A,T)
print("Magnitude: " .. tostring(mag) .. " Angle: " .. tostring(ang))
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much.